# Jquery to sum values of all elements with specific attr value

Tags: javascript, jquery, sum

I have this short menu:

```
<ul>
    <li class="voucher">
        Holidays (<span data="0" class="counter" id="119">0</span>)
        <ul id="menu2">
            <li class="voucher">
                Travel deals (<span data="119" class="counter" id="123">1</span>)
            </li>
            <li class="voucher">
                Hotel offers (<span data="119" class="counter" id="120">2</span>)
            </li>
            <li class="voucher">
                Villas offers(<span data="119" class="counter" id="121">1</span>)
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

and this js which has to collect all subcategories values in () and add that sum as (value ) for the main category Holidays:

```
var sum = 0;
$('.counter').each(function () {
    var counter = $(this).html();
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    if (counter == 0) {
        // here I want to find and sum all values in ( ) for span that has attr data equal to 119 which is the id of the main category Holidays
        sum += parseInt($('span').find("[data='" + id + "']").html(), 10) || 0;
        alert(sum);
        //here I want the sum of all subcategories -Holidays ( 4 )
        $(this).html(sum);
    }
});
```

but it doesn't work.. No errors, just doesnt sum correct and returns always 0
Please help with this if you are OK with JS,

Here is jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/europe77/w1uL5a8o/1/

Comment: Try using `.val()` or `.text()` instead of `.html()`

Comment: afaolek html() returns NULL text() returns '' / nothing..
I think the selector is not OK or maybe I need to transfer the string in () into numbers? What is it?

Comment: Are you using a debugger? Chrome would quite happily let you view the process of the loop to see where the error was.

You do need to use .text() instead of html as that will give you the full span statement.

Comment: No, I am Mozilla user :)

Comment: Havent used it in a while it must have a debugger you can breakpoint on if not get a copy of chrome.

Comment: var counter = $(this).html(); should be $(this).text() 

and if (counter =="0") not (counter == 0) otherwise counter will equal <span></span> ect which means counter will never = 0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to find by data attribute in span object.You need to use:

```
parseInt($("span[data='" + id + "']").html());
```

Also there were other issue that needs to be addressed. Here is the full working code:

```
var sum = 0;
$('.counter').each(function () {
  var counter = $(this).html();
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  sum += parseInt($(this).html(), 10) || 0;
});
alert(sum);
$('.counter:eq(0)').html(sum);
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/manantwar/35tmpubx/)**

Comment: After I change it it returns 1, not 4.. Please look at the fiddle
ALSO I changed parseInt($("span[data='" + id + "']").html()) to 
parseInt($("span[data='" + id + "']").text()) and now instead of sum it sleps all values in ()
Why is that? Instead of Holiday (4) I am getting now Holidays (121)

Comment: Milind Anantwar, I am afraid we have missunderstooded :) Your demo is calcilating something but wrong.. You have this category structure:
•Holidays (4) 
◦Travel deals (1)
◦Hotel offers (3)
◦Villas offers(4)
which means the - must be Holidays (8) , not 4

Comment: @Europeuser: check now.

Comment: Milind Anantwar that's correct :) this:
//         $(this).html(sum); was doubled that's why it returned wrong sum.. I accepted your answer, thank you very much for your help mate !

Comment: Ops, did you check it mate what will do if we have more than 1 <li class="voucher">Holidays2 (<span data="0" class="counter" id="120">0</span>) - I am checking it now and it looks to doesn't work for more than 1 main category ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58896/discussion-between-milind-anantwar-and-europeuser).